# Monospace font on body breaks layout

Tags: css, monospace

I'm using [Toast](https://github.com/daneden/Toast) in order to have a simple grid system in a project. Most of the text on the site will be in a monospace font, so I've given the `body` this font like so:

```
body {
   font-family:"MonoSpaceFont", monospace;
}
```

I then for example give two divs the class of `.grid__col.grid__col--2-of-4`. That gives the two divs 50% in width and they should appear next to eachother. However, with the monospace font set on the body, the layout breaks. As if the two divs are a nudge to wide for them to fit next to eachother. I can manually set `width: 49.8%` or similar to them and that works. So for some reason, the divs become wider with the monospace font.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/tobiasger/pen/mdbwLrb

I've never experienced this problem before. It feels like a bug, but maybe this is expected behaviour? I would like to know if there is any way of working around this problem?

Comment: Seems like the same problem happens when I apply the font to a container or wrapper. If I apply the font to the element itself that should have the font, it works without breaking the layout. But as soon as I apply the font to a container and the child elements inherits the font, it breaks.

Comment: `.grid__col` uses `margin-right: -.25em;`. This seems to equate to `-4px` when using any of the default font families _except_ monospace. When using monospace the value equates to `-3.250px`. This is what brakes the layout.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thank you! Hmm. Sounds like it would be hard then to apply the monospace "globally".

Comment: There is actually an open issue on the GitHub repository relating to this https://github.com/daneden/Toast/issues/56

Comment: Yes, I saw that just now!

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom it's a "spaces between inline-blocks" problem, which does not have solid solution, therefore many new grids use flex or whatever.

However Toast grid, being inline-block grid, uses negative margin to partially mitigate the issue. And when you switch body font to "monospace" the width of a space between blocks is being changed differently, so the existing negative margin value no longer works.

Here's what you can use to change the font:

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  &.u-font--monospace .demo-item{
   font-family: monospace, monospace;
   font-size: 1em;
  }
}
```

Edit: Original Poster was on the Github July 25th. https://github.com/daneden/Toast/issues/56

Comment: Please credit the original author if you are going to copy-pasta a solution. https://github.com/daneden/Toast/issues/56

Comment: Yes, I saw the original answer on GitHub: https://github.com/daneden/Toast/issues/56 I can't see why that specific CSS would help me, but I understand that applying the font to specific child elements would work. So I'll do that.